# Change from local database to server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, hosting

I want to ask how I can change my local database in C# to a server database, I mean I want all the data that I add or modify will be stored on that server directly.
that's my connection string :
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database_name.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
how should i change it ?

Comment: Show us what your **current** connection string looks like. Also: what is the name of your remote database server - and are you connecting to a **default** (unnamed) instance on that server - or a specific, named instance? If so: *what* instance name?

Answer (score 1):

You change the connection string, from something like:

> Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

To the actual server, something like:

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Lots of examples here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: this is my connection string looks like :
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BDBIBLIO.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: @MohamedAliAissaoui add that detail to your question. And clarify whether or not you already have your SQL Server setup ready to go.

Comment: @Dale_k this string for local database i want change it to server to get acces to it with many laptops and to avoid the risk of lost all data if the computer that contain the database is corrupt